# Setting up Stackdriver on GAE running nodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm trying to find some docs on setting up Stackdriver for nodeJS running on App Engine. The docs don't appear to provide it

https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/

However, did see a video where Stackdriver (or some other way of debugging) was being used for a node based app.

https://youtu.be/jsznS0QxtYI?t=25m12s

Any links to docs / tutorials appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We're working on getting better documentation for this one very soon.  For now, the best instructions are over on the GitHub repo readme:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-nodejs

Let me know if you have any trouble!